# Find sub-string with unknown start point and indeterminate length within larger string

Tags: string, search, grep

Find sub-string with unknown start point and indeterminate length within larger string

```
(.+)([A-Z\.]+)(.+)
```

The sub-string I am trying to extract has only uppercase alphabet letters and periods: [A-Z\.]+

The sub-string is differing lengths in different documents

I do not know the length of the sub-string that precedes the sub-string I am seeking.

You can see from the grep above that the first part of the grep

```
(.+)
```

essentially grabs the whole string.

How can I create a grep that says: find X characters up UNTIL you encounter a string of only uppercase letters and periods.

(How to replace the first part of the grep?)

Example string:

```
###_random_length_data_here_###____YFJSR.BZMN.FZGTSODZY.RIVU.ZPZOQPIKC.TIVIUHIFV.HBXORXONITZMN....NUH...NTL...KTM.PESNLQ.OZQEHESQORNHLI.ULNLBMRSQ.XWK.OWEBGKTHM.EMVQFXPXCMBTSX.KRBKUU.ENP...DGW...RJB....HININSFJBJIXG.TTFDZRUBD.GIXVFMZEH.FOQU.WBFMWWVOG.HOQI.FOHZK___###_other_random_length_data_here_###
```

The data in the middle starts at an unknown index in the string and is of varying lengths depending on the document.

Expected output is just second substring:

```
YFJSR.BZMN.FZGTSODZY.RIVU.ZPZOQPIKC.TIVIUHIFV.HBXORXONITZMN....NUH...NTL...KTM.PESNLQ.OZQEHESQORNHLI.ULNLBMRSQ.XWK.OWEBGKTHM.EMVQFXPXCMBTSX.KRBKUU.ENP...DGW...RJB....HININSFJBJIXG.TTFDZRUBD.GIXVFMZEH.FOQU.WBFMWWVOG.HOQI.FOHZK
```

Underscores and pounds signs are not delimiters in the real data, just there to show some separation between the three substrings and make the example data easier to read.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and an expected output?

Comment: I added some example data; the underscores and pounds signs are not delimiters in the real data, just there to show some separation between the three substrings and make the example data easier to read.

Comment: What is your EXACT expected output for your above string?

Comment: Just the middle substring. I am using a text editor with grep and am hoping to use bulk search and replace: (.+)([A-Z\.]+)(.+); and replace with $2.

Comment: refer my answer below!

Comment: can you provide feedback then and there for a more quick problem solving way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `GNU grep` with `-E` flag for extended regular expression syntax matches, which matches `[A-Z]`, or `.` and multiple instances of it,

```
grep -Eo '[A-Z|.]+' file
YFJSR.BZMN.FZGTSODZY.RIVU.ZPZOQPIKC.TIVIUHIFV.HBXORXONITZMN....NUH...NTL...KTM.PESNLQ.OZQEHESQORNHLI.ULNLBMRSQ.XWK.OWEBGKTHM.EMVQFXPXCMBTSX.KRBKUU.ENP...DGW...RJB....HININSFJBJIXG.TTFDZRUBD.GIXVFMZEH.FOQU.WBFMWWVOG.HOQI.FOHZK
```

(or) using `egrep`

```
egrep -o '[A-Z|.]+' file
YFJSR.BZMN.FZGTSODZY.RIVU.ZPZOQPIKC.TIVIUHIFV.HBXORXONITZMN....NUH...NTL...KTM.PESNLQ.OZQEHESQORNHLI.ULNLBMRSQ.XWK.OWEBGKTHM.EMVQFXPXCMBTSX.KRBKUU.ENP...DGW...RJB....HININSFJBJIXG.TTFDZRUBD.GIXVFMZEH.FOQU.WBFMWWVOG.HOQI.FOHZK
```

Run a loop like this inside the folder containing the binary `.txt` files,

```
for file in *.txt
do
   grep -Eao '[A-Z|.]+' "$file" >> outputFile.txt
done
```

(or) a command-line friendly version inside the folders containing the text files,

```
for file in *.txt; do grep -Eao '[A-Z|.]+' "$file" >> outputFile.txt; done
```

This runs the `grep` with the `regex` to all the files in the directory and appends it to the `outputFile.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your suggestion find the match. My hope was to strip away the unneeded substrings of the string leaving just the needed string of each file within a directory.

Comment: @verbatim: You want to retain only these lines in the file and delete other words?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to keep just the string of [A-Z\.]+ and discard everything else in each file. I have a directory of files and need to clean up files for just that data. then merge the into one large .txt file.

Comment: Yes. I have tried various command line options. I guess I am just not very versed in command line.

Comment: All files are .txt

Comment: @verbatim: Run `for file in *.txt; do grep -Eo '[A-Z|.]+' "$file" >> outputFile.txt; done` on command line, containing all text files.

Comment: The output file returned:
Binary file txt2016-02-23.txt matches
Binary file txt2016-02-24.txt matches
Binary file txt2016-02-26.txt matches

Comment: Just a list of "Binary file txt2016-02-22.txt matches" naming each file in directory.

Comment: @verbatim: Can you add the `a` flag as in my update, to treat the files for `grep` as binary and let me know?

Comment: It seems to have worked. However, these are data files that work as input to software. There must be some special hex/ascii characters in some of the files. As not all files are returning output.

Comment: Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: @verbatim: The logic is there. Now you can tweak on it there to change the file encoding to change to normal text files and apply the `grep` without `-a` for non-binary files